# DUMP cannot output anything

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is my Pig script and input data, and when executing DUMP F1, the output is correct, but when executing DUMP F2, the output is () -- seems empty, anything wrong with either input data or code?

I expect the output of DUMP F2 to be (1),(3),(5),(12).

```
hadoop fs -text input.txt
({(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)},{(1),(3),(5),(12)})

-- ({(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)},{(1),(3),(5),(12)})
A = load 'input.txt' AS (B1:bag{T:tuple(val:int)},B2:bag{T:tuple(val:int)});

F1 = foreach A generate B1;
F2 = foreach A generate B2;
DUMP F1;
DUMP F2;

output of DUMP F1:
({(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)})

output of DUMP F2:
()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default LOAD looks for tab(\t) delimited data. You can either use tab as delimiter in input.txt or based on the interest delimiter use right function for loading data with the USING clause.

Ref : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#comments

Have the content of input.txt as below and try executing the script. You should be able to see the dump result of F2.

**input.txt :**

```
{(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)}   {(1),(3),(5),(12)}
```